# Entity Framework Linq query unrelated child tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 to generated the entities and data model.

If I have two tables: Orders -> OrderDetails, with a relation between them (OrderId), then I can get all the orders and related OrderDetails with the following query

```
dbContext.Order().Include(a => a.OrderDetails);
```

But if I created a view (vOrder) for Orders, then there is no direct relation between vOrder and OrderDetails in the model, though I can link them together with joins on OrderId. How could I still get all the data from vOrder and related OrderDetails. The following query doesn't work unless I add all the navigation properties manually.

```
dbContext.vOrder().Include(a => a.OrderDetails);
```

Is there a simple LINQ query to accomplish the intended query?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Do a manual join and return an anonymous object that contains both.

Something like:

```
dbContext.vOrder
  .GroupJoin(
    dbContext.OrderDetails,
    v=>v.orderid,
    od=>o.orderid,
    (v,od)=>new {v=v,od=od});
```

Of course, you could just add the appropriate naviation properties on to vOrder and do exactly what you said.

Comment: Thanks very much and it is working. I might try to add a navigation property on the view too to see which one is better.

Comment: I think you'll find that adding the navigation property will be better as it becomes re-usable throughout your entire project, and simplifies your queries considerably.  I'd suggest a navigation property from vOrder to Order. You can always grab the details from Order's navigation property if you want.

Comment: Navigation properties are like street signs saying "Turn here to get my detail data" to the developers, so they result in generally less code, but the the ORM or RDBMS navigation properties often get additional benefits like indexes. Navigation properties provide reusable code and reusable code patterns, use them when ever you have identified an optimal way of navigating between two entities

Answer (score 0):

Why not just include more columns in the view (or create another view that has all the required data, if you don't want to modify the first one)?

Comment: There is a one-to-many relation between the view and the detail table.